# Connect .sks to skscene.h

Tags: ios, xcode

So I have a .sks Sprite Kit Scene file in which I can visually place objects (somewhat like Sprite Kit's version of the interface builder right?). I also have an SKScene.h header and SKScene.m file where I can write code for an SKScene. How do I connect the .sks scene to the .h SKScene header? Sorry this is so basic but I am stumped.

Comment: Seems like a reasonable thing to do. I've tried the obvious way by creating an IBOutlet but no way to make the connection..

Answer (score 0):

Actually you have to define the connection in .m file not .h file,
bellow is a sample code

```
@implementation SKScene (Unarchive)

+ (instancetype)unarchiveFromFile:(NSString *)file {
    /* Retrieve scene file path from the application bundle */
    NSString *nodePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:file ofType:@"sks"];
    /* Unarchive the file to an SKScene object */
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:nodePath
                                          options:NSDataReadingMappedIfSafe
                                            error:nil];
    NSKeyedUnarchiver *arch = [[NSKeyedUnarchiver alloc] initForReadingWithData:data];
    [arch setClass:self forClassName:@"SKScene"];
    SKScene *scene = [arch decodeObjectForKey:NSKeyedArchiveRootObjectKey];
    [arch finishDecoding];

    return scene;
}

@end

@implementation GameViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Configure the view.
    SKView * skView = (SKView *)self.view;
    skView.showsFPS = YES;
    skView.showsNodeCount = YES;
    /* Sprite Kit applies additional optimizations to improve rendering performance */
    skView.ignoresSiblingOrder = YES;

    // Create and configure the scene.
    GameScene *scene = [GameScene unarchiveFromFile:@"GameScene"];
    scene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleModeAspectFill;

    // Present the scene.
    [skView presentScene:scene];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't use unarchiveFromFile method, because I can't find it in the existing SpriteKit class structure, and I don't really need to write it on my own. I found another way to use it, much simpler, and it works fine in XCode 7:
1. I have the .sks file with the nodes inside it designed nicely using the UI interface.
2. I also have the .h and .m file with the same names as the .sks file. So, if I have Scene1.sks, then I also have Scene1.h and Scene1.m files.
3. In Scene1.h I have the code indicating that it is a SKScene:

```
@interface Scene1 : SKScene
```

In Scene1.m I just use this way to interact with the visually added objects:

```
SKNode *heroPositionNode = [self childNodeWithName:@"hero"];
```

where heroPositionNode is my variable that I want to work with - here or elsewhere in my code. The "hero" is the name of node inside the .sks - in the UI designer itself.
4. In GameViewController, I just use this:

```
Scene1 *scene = [Scene1 nodeWithFileNamed:@"Scene1"];  
scene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleModeAspectFill;
[skView presentScene:scene];
```

This just works. It seems that everything is connected automatically. Hope it helps, let me know if it works for you too.