# iOS Level Editor not connecting to my skscene

Tags: ios, sprite-kit

So I've created my app, but I didn't start by using the SKScene template.  At least I'm almost certain I didn't do this.  Now I want to do some level design but when I created the .sks file, used the unarchiveFromFile method that I added to the SKScene class, and start the scene I don't see anything.

Does anyone know of any configuration steps I may have missed here?

Thanks much.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I figured it out....and for everyones info my post is similar to [Connect .sks to skscene.h](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29044849/connect-sks-to-skscene-h) but here is what I was doing wrong.

I didn't include the scalingMode in my code and so it didn't work.  What I did that worked was take code from that last post and stick it in mine.

```
scene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleModeAspectFill;
```

....or whatever scaleMode you want.